# Admin-on-rest: Filter based on different data

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have a REST endpoint to get a set of 'groups', where each group consists of a name and an id. I have successfully implemented that as a resource in admin-on-rest.

Now I have another REST endpoint for getting users, but I can only get users for a specific group, not all users in general. The REST endpoint requires me to provide the group id as part of the url. There is no groupId in a user object though, because there reference is the other way around, group -> users.

What I want is to display the 'name' of a group in the filter dropdown of the users list view and then to use the 'id' of a group to pass to the rest client in order to load the respective users.

I have already implemented the call in my restclient as follows:

```
    case 'users': {
        switch(type) {
            case 'GET_LIST': {
                return getUsers(token, params.filter.id)
                    .then(response => ({ data: response.data, total: response.data.length }));
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

And in the list view of my users resource component, I have implemented a filter like this:

```
const UsersFilter = ({ ...props }) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <ReferenceInput source="id" reference="groups">
            <SelectInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceInput>
    </Filter>
);
```

Now, this doesn't work. In the filter I just one entry called 'Id', and there is an error message saying something like "cannot find targetusergroup with id==undefined".

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,

it actually did work, but I was too stupid to use the User Interface. I didn't know, that I have to first select a filter, before I can use it. And I also forgot to give my group filter a label, that's why it only said 'id' in the filter menu.

Now it works.